# Forgot to sign my checklist but checked all the boxes for the UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

I forgot to sign my name on the checklist, but Idid the electronic signature at the fingerprint center.

I realized it the next day so I re-printed the checklist and signed it, then sent it to the consulate.

Will my application be rejected for this reason?

Answer (score 1):

I have forgotten to sign the checklist on two occasions in the past and still received the visa. Though each visa application center probably has its own set of rules, so it may vary in your case. But keep in mind that the checklist only serves to confirm if you've submitted all the documents, and should not really have any bearing on your visa decision.

Comment: Thank you so much! I sent it to the British Consulate General in New York, hope they will be OK with it..I did receive a confirmation that they received my application today, I will update my progress so that other people have the same problem will have a reference here.

Comment: @ShellHofstadter I am in the same situation, Did they return your application or everything was fine? thanks

Comment: Hi sparta93, everything was fine!